# Dotnetcore got error while I connect to Database: SEHException: 'External component has thrown an exception.'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localdb

Whenever I try to connect to database, I've got this Error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: 'External component has thrown an exception.'
```

I try code first approach, database approach, and model first but still have this error. I have no problem with `Windows form` and classic `ASP.NET MVC Framework` but in dotnetcore!
I made a new blank `dotnet core` project and add services to ConfigureServices() in `Startup.cs' like this:

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<Models.ShoppingListDBContext>();
        services.AddControllers();
    }
```

Experts, Do you have any Idea?

Facts:

- Dotnet Core ver 3.1
- Admin Privilege
- I'm sure about `connection string` and I even try `MSSQLServer` and got the same error.
- the Inner Exception is null.

[image: shot]

Anybody encounters this error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove

```
Database.EnsureCreated();
```

from constructor and modify your Program#Main like this:

```
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var webHost = CreateHostBuilder(args)
            .Build();

        using var scope = webHost.Services.CreateScope();
        var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<BlogDataContext>();
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();

        await webHost.RunAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but my error came to `program.cs`! still ugly

Comment: Let's try to replace Database.EnsureCreated() with Database.Migrate()

Comment: almost nothing change, I think the problem is somewhere else... maybe dependency or Windows

Comment: Yes, probably. But you should use my code anyway. Please try to download a getting-started project from Microsoft and see if you can make that run. Then you can compare that code with yours.